# Why does my https origin not have permission to use navigator Geolocation service?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari, geolocation

When attempting to get a users position with the following code:

```
var geoLocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(BingMap.map);

geoLocationProvider.getCurrentPosition(
{
    showAccuracyCircle: false,
    timeout: 6000,
    successCallback: function (object) {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            //alert(ret);
            SearchViewModel.ConsoleLog("watchPosition first try from getCurrentPosition successCallback");

            BingMap.SetGPSLoading();
            BingMap.trackingID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(BingMap.navigatorSuccess, BingMap.navigatorFail, { maximumAge: 4000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
        }
    },
    errorCallback: function (error) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            console.log(error);
            alert(error.internalError.message);
            SearchViewModel.ConsoleLog("watchPosition first try from getCurrentPosition errorCallback");
            BingMap.SetGPSLoading();
            BingMap.trackingID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(BingMap.navigatorSuccess, BingMap.navigatorFail, { maximumAge: 4000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
        }
    }

});
```

I am receiving an error on iOS10 devices in both my native application and Safari browsers that tells me my **Origin (https://domain.com) does not have permission to use the Geolocation service**. The test server the code is on has a self signed certificate, so I don't know if that is the problem or there is another configuration issue somewhere.

As a side note, all applicable keys have been added to my info.plist file for the native iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of questions:

1. Did you add your API key to it? (using the 'credentials' parameter)
2. What license are you using developer/enterprise? Your license may have limited credentials.
3. Do you know there are different types of services within Bing maps API? read [here](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/choose-your-bing-maps-API.aspx). Look at the Platforms table. iOS (and even Android) isn't supported.